# Automate Creation of Github Topics During Repository Initialization

Tags: github, github-actions, github-webhook

In regards to Github Topics: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/classifying-your-repository-with-topics

Is there a way to automate the creation of these topics/tags? For example, when a repository within the organization is initialized, I want to get that event via a webhook and then automatically add a Topic called - "abc-repo". Is it possible to do something like this?

I've been reading and haven't seen a way to automate this process. It appears they are just added via the Github interface from within the repository itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topics can be set using the [repositories REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos).  If you create the repository via the API, you can pass the `topics` element with a list of topics you'd like, or you can update an existing repository using a `PATCH` request.